# Efficient encoding of basic numeric datatypes in protobuffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, performance

In Protobuffers documentation, it has been given

```
"For historical reasons, repeated fields of basic numeric types aren't encoded as 

efficiently as they could be. New code should use the special option [packed=true] to get 

a more efficient encoding. For example:

repeated int32 samples = 4 [packed=true];"
```

Can someone clearly explain how does the statement "packed=true" improve the efficieny of encoding basic numeric datatypes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, under the original encoding the field header (which is composed of the wire type combined with the field-number, bit-shifted and or'd) occurs for every element. Because the header is varint encoded, it is at least one byte per element, but possibly more. So 10 4-byte floats would be at least 50 bytes and quite possibly 90 bytes if the header takes 5 bytes (large field numbers take more space than small field numbers).

With the packed encoding, the field header occurs only once, followed by a varint that indicates the number of bytes to follow. So for 10 floats, the payload length is 40, which is varint-encoded in a single byte for the length prefix. At deserialization time it simply consumes that-many bytes, reading elements as it does so. Therefore for the same data (50 to 90 bytes previously) we are now using 42 to 46 bytes (again, for the range of field numbers that take 1 to 5 bytes each).

These 2 layouts are very different on the wire, and code expecting one can not usually decode the other. As such, it needs to be explicitly enabled to prevent breaking existing messages.

Comment: Also i just want to whether any similar kind of optimization technique s available for repeated field containing large number of objects?

Comment: @aarish no, simple values only